# Jvector Map Plugin issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hope someone can help me out. I found this nice jQuery plugin to display vector maps in our intranet but I'm not able to create the HTML code to make it work.

http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/

I would appreciate your assistance or guidance.

Thank you,
Tony

Answer (score 3):

Probably you forgot to set size of container inside of which you want to place the map. This should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.vector-map.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.vector-map.js"></script>
    <script src="world-en.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#map').vectorMap();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

*I will add width and height parameters in the next version*

Answer (score 1):

You must set your map. which name is on top of map.js. Probably you forgot

```
$('#map').vectorMap({map: 'europe_en'});
```